# How to scrape on only certain tags that are all in the same class?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im creating this program which allows me to scrape all the names and abilities of characters from this website. The tags (li) which contain the information I need are mixed in with other li tags that are not needed.

I have tried selecting different classes but that wont work.

Here is my code:

```
import bs4, requests, lxml, re, time, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

def webscrape():
    res = requests.get('https://www.usgamer.net/articles/15-11-2017-skyrim-guide-for-xbox-one-and-ps4-which-races-and-character-builds-are-the-best')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    races_list = soup.find_all("li < strong")
    races_list_text = [f.text.strip() for f in races_list]
    print(races_list_text)
    time.sleep(1)
webscrape()
```

It is expected to print out all the races and their corresponding information.

Comment: You should include some example html that has tags you want and tags you want to exclude.

Comment: What do you mean? I've stated the tags that I need.

Comment: I mean that you should include a sample of the html you are parsing so that we can test your solution and any solution we may come up with. Preferably the sample html will have tags you want to keep and some you want to exclude - something we can copy from your question.. please read [mcve]

Comment: For my particular question, its a bit difficult to show the key parts, Its really best for someone to look at it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.usgamer.net/articles/15-11-2017-skyrim-guide-for-xbox-one-and-ps4-which-races-and-character-builds-are-the-best')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

#one  list of tuples
race_info = [ (item.text, item.next_sibling) for item in soup.select('h2 ~ ul strong')]
# separate lists
races, abilities = zip(*[ (item.text, item.next_sibling) for item in soup.select('h2 ~ ul strong')])
```

A dictionary might be nicer in which case you can do

```
race_info = [ (item.text, item.next_sibling) for item in soup.select('h2 ~ ul strong')]
race_info = dict(race_info)
```

The `~` is a [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators):

> The ~ combinator selects siblings. This means that the second element
>   follows the first (though not necessarily immediately), and both share
>   the same parent.